# how to change localhost from false to true?

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, command

```
"snapMaxFileSizeKB": 1024,
    "upldr": ["upldr1", "upldr3", "upldr5", "upldrg1", "upldrg5", "cluster"],
    "localhost": false
  },
  "app": "dtube/0.7",
  "beneficiary": "dtube",
  "dmca": true,
  "pageTitleSeparator": "-",
  "appName": "DTube",
  "ipfs": "",
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please [edit] this question to provide context. What is this file? Why do you want to change it? With more information, maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your data was corrupt. I had to recreate the data by adding some structure to make a working sample. In JavaScript your data would look like this.

```
var someVariable = {
  "server":{
    "snapMaxFileSizeKB": 1024,
    "upldr": ["upldr1", "upldr3", "upldr5", "upldrg1", "upldrg5", "cluster"],
    "localhost": false
  },
  "app": "dtube/0.7",
  "beneficiary": "dtube",
  "dmca": true,
  "pageTitleSeparator": "-",
  "appName": "DTube",
  "ipfs": "",

};
```

This is a basic object. To access the object try

```
console.log(someVariable.server.localhost);
```

Or try

```
console.log(someVariable["server"]["localhost"]);
```

When setting the value try:

```
someVariable.server.localhost = "some value";
someVariable["server"]["localhost"] = "some other value";
```